# Some trouble with subclass constructor

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, constructor

Let say I have this example:

```
class A : SomeAbstractClassWithProperties
{
  public A(string id, int size)
  {
    this.Name = "Name1";
    this.Something = new SomethingElse(id, size);
  }

  //...some stuff
}

class B : A
{
  public B(string id, int size)
  {
    this.Name = "Name2";
    this.Something = new SomethingElse(id, size);
  }
}
```

Ok this is not gonna work:

```
Inconsistent accessibility: base class A is less accessible than class 'B'
'A' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments
```

But as we see the constructor of **Class A** and **Class B** are almost the same. Just **this.Name** is different. How could I rewrite **class B**? Any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: It's a bit entertaining that everyone has posted answer with copied invalid constructor declaration `public CLASS B(string id, int size){/*stuff*/}` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please update your code

```
class B : A
{
  public class B(string id, int size) : base(id, size) 
  { 
     this.Name = "Name2";
  }
}
```

The case is you B constructor tries to call A() default constructor which desn't exists.

Answer (score 0):

You should add default (without parameters) constructor  to class A or modify constructor of class B like this

```
public class B(string id, int size) : base(id, size)
  {
    this.Name = "Name2";
    this.Something = new SomethingElse(id, size);
  }
```

Comment: Do I really need to add this.Something = new SomethingElse(id, size); again?

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating an instance of B, since B extends from A you will have so call the constructor for A too.
Since you are defining a constructor to class A, you no longer have the default parameter-less constructor, so you will have to call the constructor of A in the B constructor passing the needed parameters.

```
public A(string id,int size):base(param1,param2...paramX)
```